# Function is executing before asynchronous function even though callback used

Tags: javascript

When I pass LoadTask2 as a callback, I am getting LoadTask2 executed before reading the text file done. what could be the reason and how can I make LoadTask2 to be executed after reading the text file?

```
LoadTask1(LoadTask2);

function LoadTask1(LoadTask2) {
  let parEtask1Pending = document.getElementById('task1Status');
  parEtask1.replaceChild(loadingE, parEtask1Pending);
  currentIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
    readTextFile("file1.txt", getTextData);
  }, 2000);
  LoadTask2();
}

function LoadTask2() {
  console.log("Task2")
}

function readTextFile(file, callback) {
  console.log('Reading file..')
  var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
  rawFile.open("GET", "textFiles/" + file, true);
  rawFile.onload = function() {

    if (this.status === 200) {
      getTextData(this.responseText);

    }

  }
  rawFile.send();
}
```

Output comes as: Task2->Reading file.

Comment: "what could be the reason"...because you aren't waiting for readTextFile to complete (or even start in fact, due to the interval!) before you call LoadTask2(). If you really want LoadTask2 to wait until everything in readTextFile has completed then... `if(this.status===200){
          getTextData(this.responseText);LoadTask2();

        }` is the only way - that's the only place in the code where you can be certain that the AJAX call has finished.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
function LoadTask1(LoadTask2) {
   let parEtask1Pending = document.getElementById('task1Status');
   parEtask1.replaceChild(loadingE, parEtask1Pending);
   currentIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
     readTextFile("file1.txt", getTextData);
   }, 2000);
   LoadTask2();
}
```

javascript wont wait for the `setInterval` till its completed. The `setInterval` gets executed and starts to run "parallel".

Possible solution is to add an promise in your `readTextFile` like this:

```
  readTextFile = function(file) {
     return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        console.log('Reading file..')
        var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
        rawFile.open("GET", "textFiles/" + file, true);
        rawFile.onload = function() {

        if (rawFile.status === 200) {
           resolve(rawFile.responseText);
        }
        rawFile.send();
     }
}
```

now you can put an `.then()` on your function:

```
function LoadTask1(LoadTask2) {
   let parEtask1Pending = document.getElementById('task1Status');
   parEtask1.replaceChild(loadingE, parEtask1Pending);
   readTextFile("file1.txt").then(function(response){
      console.log("your response: " + response);
      LoadTask2();
   })     
}
```

There is also another modern solution with `async/await`. You can do it like this too:

```
 async function LoadTask1(LoadTask2) {
   let parEtask1Pending = document.getElementById('task1Status');
   parEtask1.replaceChild(loadingE, parEtask1Pending);
   const responseText = await readTextFile("file1.txt");
   console.log(responseText);
   LoadTask2();     
}
```

This should work, i didnt tested it yet.

One more thing here in this function:

```
function readTextFile(file, callback) {
      console.log('Reading file..')
      var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
      rawFile.open("GET", "textFiles/" + file, true);
      rawFile.onload = function() {

      if (this.status === 200) {
         getTextData(this.responseText);

      }

    }
 rawFile.send();
}
```

You actually dont pass nothing back to your callback function. you should rename `getTextData(this.responseText)` to `callback(this.responseText)` and then execute your task2 in your callback function like this:

```
function readTextFile(file, callback) {
      console.log('Reading file..')
      var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
      rawFile.open("GET", "textFiles/" + file, true);
      rawFile.onload = function() {

      if (this.status === 200) {
         callback(this.responseText);

      }

    }
 rawFile.send();
}

function LoadTask1(LoadTask2) {
   let parEtask1Pending = document.getElementById('task1Status');
   parEtask1.replaceChild(loadingE, parEtask1Pending);
   readTextFile("file1.txt", function(response){
      console.log(response);
      LoadTask2();
   });

}
```

Comment: how your above code reads my text file periodically using readTextFile ..the reason i am using setInterval is to read file1 text file periodically

Answer (score -1):

That's because it's due to the setInterval function, it will delay for 2 seconds before it execute your function.

Comment: yes but that's only one problem though. readTextFile itself also involves an asynchronous call...